# GetModuleBaseName dosen't take char* parameter

Tags: c++

I got this code:

```
DWORD64 GetModuleBase(HANDLE hProc, string &sModuleName)//For 64bit process
{
HMODULE *hModules;
hModules = 0;
char szBuf[50];
DWORD cModules = 0;
DWORD64 dwBase = 0;

EnumProcessModules(hProc, hModules, 0, &cModules);
hModules = new HMODULE[cModules / sizeof(HMODULE)];

if (EnumProcessModules(hProc, hModules, cModules / sizeof(HMODULE), &cModules)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < cModules / sizeof(HMODULE); i++) {
        if (GetModuleBaseName(hProc, hModules[i], szBuf, sizeof(szBuf))) {
            if (sModuleName.compare(szBuf) == 0) {
                dwBase = (DWORD64)hModules[i];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

delete[] hModules;

return dwBase;
}
```

that fails on this line telling me that char* is incompatible with LPWSTR

```
if (GetModuleBaseName(hProc, hModules[i], szBuf, sizeof(szBuf))) {
```

I've been using it in another project for a long time and it was working fine, but I recently moved to a fresh one and I'm getting this issue. Not sure what to do. Adding (LPWSTR) next to szbuf just makes the dll crash.

I'm using VS 2013

Comment: project property, generate, use multi-byte set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `GetModuleBaseNameA` (add "A" to the tail) instead.

`GetModuleBaseNameA` explicitly use ANSI characters in contrast to `GetModuleBaseName`, which is a macro to be `GetModuleBaseNameA` or `GetModuleBaseNameW`.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks. I'll accept the answer when I'll be able to

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @MikeCAT answers this specific question, but I think you might run into problems later ahead, when you start mixing `TCHAR`/`LPTSTR`-strings (or `wchar_t`-strings) with `char`-strings.

If you want to use `char` strings rather than `wchar_t` string (called 'Unicode' by MSVC) then it's probably a good idea to write your entire application to use either one or the other and set the Character Encoding to the corresponding character set, which can be done in the project property page. 'Multi-byte Character Set' corresponds to `char`, and 'Unicode Character Set' corresponds to `wchar_t`.

This also has the side-effect that your `GetModuleBaseName` will automatically switch to the `char`-version, namely `GetModuleBaseNameA`. There are quite a few Windows APIs which 'switch' depending on this flag.

Therefore, the correct solution is most likely to set this flag to use the `char` version and then use `GetModuleBaseName`, without the 'A'.

Comment: The problem is that MS seems to be deprecating use of the Multi-Byte Character Set, at least for MFC projects.  And, you might want to be able to copy code from one project to another without worrying about Unicode/MBCS settings.  So in my opinion, wherever you pass non-TCHAR (or CString) text to one of these Win32 functions, the A or W postfix should be included explicitly.

Comment: @ChristopherOicles I wanted to keep things a bit simpler for this post. But, if you want to support both MBCS and Unicode in a way that you can copy the code directly, then you need to write your application completely in `TCHAR`-style. Using this style, you never use explicit A or W versions and just let the macro's choose for you; actually, this is what you 'always' do when using the Windows API in C++. The alternative is choosing one encoding and going with that. Considering this is the simplest option to explain and use, I recommend it here.

Comment: Yes, by all means, use TCHAR and CString where you can, but sometimes you find yourself with a const char* or std::string (from some non-MS library you are using), and your're working on a Unicode project -- is it simpler to tack an "A" on to the end of a function's name or use one of those horrible conversion functions?